# "map(From)' in 'Mapper' clashes with 'map(Object)' in 'CursorToMessageImpl'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**This is code in kotlin. Showing error Type inference failed: inline fun  T.apply(block: T.() -> Unit): T cannot be applied to receiver: Message  arguments: (Message.() -> Any) .**

**map(From)' in 'Mapper' clashes with 'map(Object)' in 'CursorToMessageImpl'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
**

```
class CursorToMessageImpl @Inject constructor(
private val context: Context,
private val cursorToPart: CursorToPart,
private val keys: KeyManager,
private val permissionManager: PermissionManager,
private val preferences: Preferences) : CursorToMessage
```

```
{
private val uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/complete-conversations")
    private val projection = arrayOf(
            MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN,
            MmsSms._ID,
            Mms.DATE,
            Mms.DATE_SENT,
            Mms.READ,
            Mms.THREAD_ID,
            Mms.LOCKED,

            Sms.ADDRESS,
            Sms.BODY,
            Sms.SEEN,
            Sms.TYPE,
            Sms.STATUS,
            Sms.ERROR_CODE,

            Mms.SUBJECT,
            Mms.SUBJECT_CHARSET,
            Mms.SEEN,
            Mms.MESSAGE_TYPE,
            Mms.MESSAGE_BOX,
            Mms.DELIVERY_REPORT,
            Mms.READ_REPORT,
            MmsSms.PendingMessages.ERROR_TYPE,
            Mms.STATUS
    )

    override fun map(from: Pair<Cursor, CursorToMessage.MessageColumns>): Message {
        val cursor = from.first
        val columnsMap = from.second

        return Message().apply {
            type = when {
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MmsSms.TYPE_DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN) != -1 -> cursor.getString(columnsMap.msgType)
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Mms.SUBJECT) != -1 -> "mms"
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Sms.ADDRESS) != -1 -> "sms"
                else -> "unknown"
            }

            id = keys.newId()
            threadId = cursor.getLong(columnsMap.threadId)
            contentId = cursor.getLong(columnsMap.msgId)
            date = cursor.getLong(columnsMap.date)
            dateSent = cursor.getLong(columnsMap.dateSent)
            read = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.read) != 0
            locked = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.locked) != 0
            subId = if (columnsMap.subId != -1) cursor.getInt(columnsMap.subId)

            else -1

            when (type) {
                "sms" -> {
                    address = cursor.getString(columnsMap.smsAddress) ?: ""
                    boxId = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.smsType)
                    seen = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.smsSeen) != 0

                    body = columnsMap.smsBody
                            .takeIf { column -> column != -1 } // The column may not be set
                            ?.let { column -> cursor.getString(column) } ?: "" // cursor.getString() may return null

                    errorCode = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.smsErrorCode)
                    deliveryStatus = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.smsStatus)
                }

                "mms" -> {
                    address = getMmsAddress(contentId)
                    boxId = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsMessageBox)
                    date *= 1000L
                    dateSent *= 1000L
                    seen = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsSeen) != 0
                    mmsDeliveryStatusString = cursor.getString(columnsMap.mmsDeliveryReport) ?: ""
                    errorType = if (columnsMap.mmsErrorType != -1) cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsErrorType) else 0
                    messageSize = 0
                    readReportString = cursor.getString(columnsMap.mmsReadReport) ?: ""
                    messageType = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsMessageType)
                    mmsStatus = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsStatus)
                    val subjectCharset = cursor.getInt(columnsMap.mmsSubjectCharset)
                    subject = cursor.getString(columnsMap.mmsSubject)
                            ?.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() }
                            ?.let(_root_ide_package_.app.google.android.mms.pdu_alt.PduPersister::getBytes)
                            ?.let { _root_ide_package_.app.google.android.mms.pdu_alt.EncodedStringValue(subjectCharset, it).string } ?: ""
                    textContentType = ""
                    attachmentType = Message.AttachmentType.NOT_LOADED

                    parts.addAll(cursorToPart.getPartsCursor(contentId)?.map { cursorToPart.map(it) } ?: listOf())
                }
                else -> -1
            }
        }
    }


**and interference mapper is :-**


interface Mapper<in From, out To> {

    fun map(from: From): To
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is your issue, but since `else -> -1` in your `when` statement doesn't accomplish anything, try removing it. A `when` statement doesn't have to be exhaustive when it isn't being forced to be evaluated as an expression (by assigning its result to a variable or property).

`else -> -1` at the bottom of your `when` statement causes it to be a `when` *expression* that returns `Any`. Usually, the compiler can interpret a lambda ending in an expression other than Unit as having an implicit return of `Unit` if there are no overloads that it would otherwise match. But there may be some cases where the involved classes are complex enough to prevent it from deducing that.